# JNLP file and other requirements for deployment of JavaFX 2.0 application in web browser

Tags: java, jnlp, javafx-2

I need to create a JNLP file for a online Application i have developed in JavaFX 2.0... I have no idea where to start since there is no documentation that relates a JNLP file to a JAVAFX 2.0 application on the web currently...at least none that I have found. I kind of would like this page to be a tutorial of how to go from code to deployment to a browser.

I would like the application to load when the page loads. Similar to the ensemble sample for JavaFX 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation directly on javafx.com: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/packaging.htm#BABFECGG

But it is a bit complex, so you can opt for an easier way : install NetBeans 7.1 Beta, create JavaFX project there and click "Clean and Build". NB7.1 will create all required files.

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/